# javascript image animation blink between two images

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, setinterval

Hi I was wondering if anybody knows how to get two images to change between one another with half second intervals?
Start button begins the animation, stop button stops it on what ever it is currently showing. If you can show me how to at least get the animation going ill be happy. Stopping it is just a bonus.

```js
var start;
function setTime()
{
  start = 1;
  carSchedule = setInterval(carChange, 500);
}

function carChange()
{   
  var imageData;
  if (start == 1)
  {
    imageData = document.getElementById("car");
    imageData.src = "https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff";
  }

  else if(start == 2)
  {
    imageData = document.getElementById("car");
    imageData.src = "https://dummyimage.com/600x400/ff00ff/0011ff";
  }
}
```

```html
<button onClick = "carChange()">Start Animation</button>
<button onCLick = "stop()">Strop Animation</button>
<br/>
<img id="car">
```

Comment: Instead of changing src, show/hide the images - for sure preload the images

Comment: Use fadeIn,fadeOut jquery

Answer (score 2):

You could store your images in an `Array` and loop through them using a `setInterval` :

```js
let srcs = [
  'http://www.catster.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/A-fluffy-cat-looking-funny-surprised-or-concerned.jpg',
  'https://images.pexels.com/photos/617278/pexels-photo-617278.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350'
];

//Preload your images
let imgs = srcs.map(src => {
  let img = new Image();
  img.src = src;
  return img
});

let img = document.getElementById('car');

let current = 0; //Current image displayed
let interval;

const carChange = () => {
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (current + 1 > srcs.length - 1) current = 0;
    else current++;
    img.src = imgs[current].src
  }, 500);
}

const stop = () => {
  clearInterval(interval);
}
```

```html
<button onClick="carChange()">Start Animation</button>
<button onCLick="stop()">Stop Animation</button>
<p><img id="car" /></p>
```

Comment: Preload would improve this